# How to install opencv on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, opencv, machine-learning

Thank you in advance for your help. Im trying to install opencv on my mac and have tried multiple things including updating pip to no avail. I have tried running `pip3 install opencv-python`. I have also browsed the other forums asking similar questions.

My error message is as follows:`Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
exec(line)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 562, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
(base) Indranils-MacBook-Pro:~ Indra$ pip3 install opencv-python
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
exec(line)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 562, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
Collecting opencv-python
Using cached opencv-python-4.6.0.66.tar.gz (90.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.20.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: opencv-python
Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for opencv-python (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [166 lines of output]
Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
        exec(line)
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
  
  Remainder of file ignored
  Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:
  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
        exec(line)
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
  
  Remainder of file ignored
  Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:
  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
        exec(line)
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
  
  Remainder of file ignored
  Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:
  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
        exec(line)
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
  
  Remainder of file ignored
  Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:
  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
        exec(line)
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
  
  Remainder of file ignored
  Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:
  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
        exec(line)
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
  
  Remainder of file ignored
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/private/var/folders/qq/y8yzfp3n5gv8_zh3zxlxq71r0000gn/T/pip-install-elf_n1fp/opencv-python_0a22ef9c97af4a8eb0cc10b11ea6544a/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:
  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
        exec(line)
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
  
  Remainder of file ignored
  Error processing line 1 of /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vision-1.0.0-py3.9-nspkg.pth:
  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site.py", line 169, in addpackage
        exec(line)
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 562, in module_from_spec
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
  
  Remainder of file ignored
  Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
  CMake Error at /private/var/folders/qq/y8yzfp3n5gv8_zh3zxlxq71r0000gn/T/pip-build-env-w5ujogf5/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cmake/data/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
    The C compiler
  
      "/usr/bin/cc"
  
    is not able to compile a simple test program.
  
    It fails with the following output:
  
      Change Dir: /private/var/folders/qq/y8yzfp3n5gv8_zh3zxlxq71r0000gn/T/pip-install-elf_n1fp/opencv-python_0a22ef9c97af4a8eb0cc10b11ea6544a/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
  
      Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make -f Makefile cmTC_6e1ff/fast && xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  
  
  
  
  
    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (ENABLE_LANGUAGE)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "/private/var/folders/qq/y8yzfp3n5gv8_zh3zxlxq71r0000gn/T/pip-install-elf_n1fp/opencv-python_0a22ef9c97af4a8eb0cc10b11ea6544a/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "/private/var/folders/qq/y8yzfp3n5gv8_zh3zxlxq71r0000gn/T/pip-install-elf_n1fp/opencv-python_0a22ef9c97af4a8eb0cc10b11ea6544a/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
  
  
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Ninja" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  
  
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator
  --------------------------------
  ---------------------------
  ----------------------
  -----------------
  ------------
  -------
  --
  --
  -------
  ------------
  -----------------
  ----------------------
  ---------------------------
  --------------------------------
  -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator - failure
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  ********************************************************************************
  scikit-build could not get a working generator for your system. Aborting build.
  
  Building MacOSX wheels for Python 3.9 requires XCode.
  Get it here:
  
    https://developer.apple.com/xcode/
  
  ********************************************************************************
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for opencv-python
Failed to build opencv-python
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Comment: Seems you do not have a working C/C++ compiler, and you need one: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Comment: Note: Ensure the XCode and CommandLineTools are installed in your macOS system.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your responses Dr Snoopy and vscv. Do you know how I can go about downloading xcode/command line tools and a working c/c++ compiler? I am relatively new to programming but have never faced such a situation before so am surprised it is acting up only with the open cv installation...

Answer (score 1):

Try this command.

```
xcode-select --install
```

This command will install command line tools for xcode.

Verify that you've successfully installed Xcode Command Line Tools:

```
$ xcode-select -p
```

You should see the following:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```